# Multiple Monitor Screensaver with video capability

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I'm looking for a screensaver that is capable of playing videos on multiple monitors.

At the moment I'm using Picasa with its screensaver, which is great and works perfectly using multiple monitors, but I have found that even if videos are added to the list of files, they will not be played by the screensaver.

Can anyone suggest a screensaver that can play either pictures or videos, and supports multiple monitors?

Comment: So you want it to scan for new videos in a local folder? You should make this requirement clearer.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ideally it would work exactly like the Picasa screensaver but with the ability to play videos, but failing that, I don't mind if it scans for new videos in a folder, or if I need to manually add them in advance. I just would like a screensaver that can play videos as well as pictures, over multiple monitors (I have three monitors).